# How can I avoid unnecessarily repeating the map step in chained hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I have two chained mapreduce steps (within a much larger branched workflow). The first groups by id and in a very small number of cases produces a new object with a different id (maybe a few thousand out of hundreds of millions of input objects). The second again groups everything, including the new objects, by id and produces a bunch of stuff I care about.

It seems really wasteful to read/shuffle all the data again when everything except the new objects is already on grouped same server and ordered by id. Is there a way to just shuffle the new stuff to the current reducers and have them start the list again?

I'm using Hadoop streaming so any answer that works with that would be ideal, but I'm also interested in general answers.

Answer (score 0):

If the new objects are produced by reducers, then you can't do this with MapReduce in a single pass. Consider using spark instead; it is better for iterative tasks.

If the new objects are produced by mappers, AND the first stage reducers are just pass-through, you should be able to do this in one step: The mappers in the first stage should emit both the original and new records (there's no rule that says mappers have to be 1:1. The mapper can produce more or fewer records than are input)